# Is there way to change the default timezone of laravel inside of app.php

Tags: php, laravel, phpmyadmin

I have problem regarding to current date, I just wan't to know if the default timezone of laravel in config\app.php can be change based on what timezone i wanted to be.? to understand well, I created this project in asia country but this project based on canada timezone.

Right now my date and time is
05/06/2019 on my laptop so if I used the CURDATE() expression of mysql the date and time will be also 05/06/2019, but the problem when i use the curdate() the output in phpmyadmin is not same on my computer.

[image: Output Curdate]

**The Question here: If I use the curdate expression, The output of my timezone will be based on current date and time of canada. Is it possible to change it to laravel?**

Right now i create an order which the date is 05/06/2019

[image: List of order]

I have here my script where I need to select all data based on current date but badly the output is wrong because of timezone.

```
SELECT op.order_id,op.customer_id,customer_name,customer_number,op.or_number,delivery_status,order_ship_address,delivery_status,order_date,amount,driver_firstname,transaction_number FROM order_properties as op LEFT JOIN (SELECT customer_id,order_id,amount,subtotal FROM payment) p ON op.order_id = p.order_id LEFT JOIN (SELECT customer_id,customer_name,customer_location,customer_number FROM customer_details) cd ON op.customer_id = cd.customer_id LEFT JOIN (SELECT driver_id,driver_firstname FROM driver) drive ON op.driver_id = drive.driver_id WHERE customer_location = '1790' AND DATE(order_date)=CURDATE()
```

[image: Output of my script]

Comment: maybe you can adjust the clock on your computer and set it like you're on Canada?

Comment: @kapitan i already adjust my clock on my computer.